# How to get rid of the auto-opening search on desktop?

Tags: 16.04, uninstall, search

How do I get rid of the automatically opening search feature on the desktop? I'm not sure what it's actually called. It's the box that pops up (in my lower right corner) when I press a key. It's a search option just for desktop icons, I think.

Comment: The Windows Key (dash)? Or the Alt Key (HUD)? Both are key features of Unity. To close either, simply hit the key again.

Comment: The issue is that anytime I press a character key, say "s" for example, a field opens with the letter "s" in it. I can close the field no problem, it's the fact that it opened in the first place that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using dconf-editor (had to install via terminal). On the left hand side, I opened org>gnome>nautilus>preferences, then in the right field, I found option "enable-interactive-search" and disabled it. Now, nothing happens when I randomly press a character key at the desktop.